# each и append дублируется

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

пытаюсь сделать открытие телефона по клику (для учета конверсий) есть вот такой вот код

```
<div class="appointment-clinic-phone py-3">
  <a data-phone="<?php echo $clinic['phone']; ?>" class="text-dark display-6"><span class="text-muted">Показать</span></a>
</div>
```

И Js

```
$('.appointment-clinic-phone > a').each(function() {
  var phone = $(this).data('phone');
      edit_phone = phone.slice(0, -4) + '....';
                                    
    $(this).prepend(edit_phone);

});
```

Все работает хорошо, но prepend почему-то дублируется много раз, вопрос почему(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего потому-что елементов с классом ```.appointment-clinic-phone``` больше чем вы думаете или из-за тега ```a``` внутри этого класса, по той же причине

Comment: ну так и что у вас в этом data-атрибуте в итоге?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос весь php цикл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В песочнице и ваш вариант работает отлично. Посмотрите, нет ли в других местах кода попыток вывести телефон, либо используйте костыль в виде полного перезатирания html в ссылке

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $('.appointment-clinic-phone > a').each(function() {
    let _this = $(this);
    let phone = _this.data('phone');
    let span = _this.find('span')[0].outerHTML;
    phone = phone.slice(0, -4) + '....';

    _this.html(phone + span);
  });
});
```